# Firebase cross domain authentication using only frontend

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

“Cross domain authentication” and “subdomain authentication” such questions are old and repeatedly asking questions in stack overflow. However all of the things are integrating using backend application but I need authenticate to two or more sub-domain or cross domain authentication using only front-end application and firebase.

**If it possible by using JavaScript it helps to all front-end developer.**

**If it possible to do please help me or redirect me right ref**

I have already tried as below

**Form Main Domain  http://localhost:3000 :**   Authenticated main domain use exist Signed In

```
() => {
      const { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } = require('firebase/auth')
      const auth = getAuth(app);
      onAuthStateChanged(auth, (UserCredential: any) => {
        if (UserCredential) {
          let refreshToken = UserCredential.stsTokenManager.refreshToken
          console.log(refreshToken)
          window.location.href = `http://localhost:3001/Auth?id=${refreshToken}`

        } else { console.log("User is signed out") }
      });
```

**For Sub-Domain  http://localhost:3001 :** Required to Authenticated

```
var url_string = window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var token_From_url = url.searchParams.get("id");
const auth = getAuth(app);
    signInWithCustomToken(auth, token_From_url)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            let j = userCredential.operationType
            // Signed in
            const user = userCredential.user
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            console.log("errorCode :", errorCode);
            console.log("errorMessage :", errorMessage)
        });
}
```

I got error

> errorCode : auth/invalid-custom-token Auth.tsx:23 errorMessage :

> Firebase: Invalid assertion format. 3 dot separated segments required.
> (auth/invalid-custom-token). Auth.tsx:22

Comment: have you found a solution to this?